# Generate grouped scatter plots in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in the form [SeriesName, X, Y] for a dozen or so series.
I want to create an Excel chart that contains each series plotted as a scatter plot.
This is not possible with a basic pivot table and the only other way I can think of is to manually filter-copy-paste each series into a separate table and manually add the series data to the plot.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of doing this is to build the pivot table, then create a separate table that references the cells of the pivot table.  You can then make a scatter plot from your secondary table, and it will update when you (manually) update your pivot table.

Note that when you refer to cells in the pivot table, you will want to type in the letter-number (e.g. `A1`) rather than clicking on the cell.